# "Inverting" the fourier spectrum representation of a boolean function to recover a circuit representaiton

Tags: boolean-functions, fourier-analysis, circuits

Given a boolean circuit, or an equivalent boolean expression, we can compute its fourier spectrum to yield a real-valued (multilinear) polynomial representation.  What about the other way around?  Given a the fourier spectrum of an $n$-bit boolean function, are there general methods for coverting that to a circuit?

If the degree of the polynomial representation is sufficiently small, then I can see a way to do this.  In general, however --even if the spectrum is sparse but not low-degree-- I don't know of a reasonably efficient method for creating a circuit whose spectrum is the given one.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it means to compute the Fourier spectrum of a boolean expression?